# Translating a snippet in c to pseudocode

Tags: c, pseudocode

I'm just learning Java and I have an assignment where I need to translate a snippet of C to Java. Can anybody help me by translating the snippet to pseudocode? I want to do the Java coding on my own, but I do not know C and I can't get much sense out of the snippet. This is the assignment:

---

You are looking for a simple pattern matching method. Similar to strstr (...) in C, it should search for a search string in a string. The search string should contain "*" (replacement for several characters) and "?". You have an example, but it's in C:

```
int match ( char *pat, char *str ) {
 switch ( *pat ) {
  case '\0' : return !*str;
  case '*'  : return match( pat+1, str ) || *str && match( pat, str+1 );
  case '?'  : return *str && match( pat+1, str+1 );
  default   : return *pat == *str && match( pat+1, str+1 );
 }
}
```

Translate it to Java.

---

I know it's stupid to try an assignment where you need to translate from a language you do not know and I cannot understand why this assignment is included in a list of Java learning tasks but I have to solve it and it would be very kind if anybody is willing to help me.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Perhaps you would get better help if you would show your attempt and try to describe where are your struggling at.

Comment: Note that the recursive function terminates when the string terminator is found as in `case '\0': return !*str;` and remember that in C `0` is false and anything else is true.

Comment: A `switch()` in C is about the same as in Java. This function is using recursion, calling itself, which is also available in Java. This function is using a pointer to a string of characters which is not available in Java so you will need to translate that to something that is in Java, `StringBuffer` comes first to mind however you will need to keep an index variable which is available in Java rather than relying on a pointer which is not. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried commenting it for you. Take a read and see if it helps you understand :).

```
/* Returns an integer (nonzero if the strings match, zero if they don't).
 * - pat: A string (char *) which is your pattern.
 * - str: A string (char *) which is your source string.
 * Note: All strings end in the null-character ('\0') which has integer value zero. 
*/
int match ( char *pat, char *str ) {

 /* The switch extracts the first character of the string "pat" (*pat).
  * Then, it will run the code in the case to which that character matches:
 */
 switch ( *pat ) {

  /* If you match null-character, then return nonzero only if the value 
   * of the leading character in str (*str) is zero (!*str) This means
   * that it returns a match if the leading character in str is also 
   * the null character
  */ 
  case '\0' : return !*str;

  /* If you match an asterisk '*', then return nonzero in two cases:
   * (1) Calling your own function recursively having dropped the asterisk from
   *     the pattern returns nonzero (match(pat+1, str)).
   * ... OR ... 
   * (2) The leading character of str is nonzero (*str) AND calling
   *     this very function having dropped the leading character of str returns
   *     nonzero (match(pat, str + 1)).
  */
  case '*'  : return match( pat+1, str ) || *str && match( pat, str+1 );

  /* If you match '?', then return nonzero if both cases are true:
   * (1) *str is not the null-char (it is nonzero).
   * (2) Calling match recursively having skipped the current character
   * in both the pattern AND the string returns nonzero (match(pat+1, str+1)).
  */                             
  case '?'  : return *str && match( pat+1, str+1 );


  /* Otherwise, if you didn't match on any of the above patterns, return
   * nonzero only if both the following conditions are true:
   * (1) The current character at the head of pat is the same as that of str
   *      (*pat == *str)
   * (2) calling match recursively having skipped both the current character
   *     at the head of pattern AND the string also returns nonzero. 
   *     match(pat + 1, str + 1)
  */
  default   : return *pat == *str && match( pat+1, str+1 );
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Micrified that really helps me. The pointer in C confused me very much but with your comments it's now clear how it works and what is returned. And I'm sure I'll be able to translate that into Java.

Comment: @BP13 Yes, strings in C are tricky. Java makes it much more abstract with their "String" type. If my answer is satisfactory, please remember to hit that checkmark next to my answer so I can rake in those sweet good-boy-points!

Answer (score 0):

C and Java are similar languages, so you might understand parts of the program.

There are a few important differences.
C uses `char` array for strings and marks the end of the string with a trailing `'\0'`. Similar to arrays are pointers.

In function

```
int match ( char *pat, char *str )
```

`pat` is a pointer to a pattern string, `str` is the string that should be matched.

In the function body `*pat` is the first character of the pattern. Similar for `*str`.

`pat+1` is a pointer to the next character of the string which may be followed by other characters. The next character might also be the end marker `'\0'`.

In C you can use numbers for logical operations.

```
!*str
```

is the logical negation of the value of the first character where `str` points to. `'\0'` is the value 0 (end of string) which is regarded as `false`. Any character in the string has a non-zero value and is regarded as `true`.

The return type `int` is used as a boolean. in C there is no specific `boolean` or `bool` type. For example

```
case '\0' : return !*str;
```

means: When we reached the end of the pattern (`case '\0':)` we return `true` (not 0) if `str` points to the end of the string (`'\0'`) otherwise we return `false` because the logical negation of something `!= 0` (`true`) is `0` (`false`).

Comment: Thank you for the fast response Bodo. So the switch case iterates through the string and compares to the search string, but what datatype is returned? I would expect int but isn't it boolean in this case?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I completely understood it now. The nonzero and zero returned are equivalent to true and false in terms of string consistency.